# Use of http form post

Tags: html, input

I'm porting a microsoft asp app to Wordpress. In it, I was using a form that had four different sort sequences that would change the sql SELECT used to get the data. Here is the html that I'm using to set up the form:

```
<form method="post" action="http://xxx.yyy/wp-admin/admin-post.php">
    <td width="60" height="26">
       <input type="submit"  value="Lot #">
       <input type="hidden" name="action" value="member_directory">
       <input type="hidden" name="data" value="1">
    </td>
    <td width="154"         >
       <input type="submit" value="Name">
       <input type="hidden" name="action" value="member_directory">
       <input type="hidden" name="data" value="2">
    </td>       
    <td width="154">
       <input type="submit"  value="Subdivision - Blk / Lot">
       <input type="hidden" name="action" value="member_directory">
       <input type="hidden" name="data" value="3">
    </td>
    <td width="96">
       <input type="submit" value="Address">
       <input type="hidden" name="action" value="member_directory">
       <input type="hidden" name="data" value="4">
    </td>
</form>
```

In my admin_post function I have `$request = $_REQUEST['data'];`

No matter which submit button is clicked the value of `$request` is 4.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Use the 'curly braces' in the question box here to format code so it is visible. That makes it easier to see what is going on with the code. Reformat your question to 'code' the code. (You can also use a 'code/end code' tag to format code.)

Comment: This is probably happening because you're using the name `data` multiple times. It's always `4` because that is the last one.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the problem here has nothing to do with WP or PHP, and everything to do with HTML forms and that you have multiple fields with the same name inside a form tag, and the one with 4 just happens to be the last one, so that's what the browser picks

Comment: As an aside, consider having the form page also be the form handler, or using the REST API, I don't see many people using `admin-post.php`, it's more difficult to structure things that way and introduces unnecessary redirects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, your best bet is to actually use `$_POST` to process this logic. In your form, your submit buttons lack a `name` attribute which would allow you to do this:

```
<form method="post" action="http://xxx.yyy/wp-admin/admin-post.php">
    <td width="60" height="26">
       <input type="submit" value="Lot #" name="lot">
    </td>
    <td width="154"         >
       <input type="submit" value="Name" name="name">
    </td>       
    <td width="154">
       <input type="submit"  value="Subdivision - Blk / Lot" name="subdivision">
    </td>
    <td width="96">
       <input type="submit" value="Address" name="address">
    </td>
</form>
```

And since the only real difference between the `<td>` elements is the value of `data` you can eliminate the two hidden fields.

Then in your handler you can use `if` statements to check `$_POST` to see which submit button was clicked with the `isset()` function:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['lot'] ) {
    $data = 1;
} elseif ( isset( $_POST['name'] ) ) {
    $data = 2;
} elseif ( isset( $_POST['subdivision'] ) ) {
    $data = 3;
} elseif ( isset ($_POST['address] ) ) {
    $data = 4;
} else {
    die( 'Invalid Selection' );
}

// Rest of your handler goes here
```

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you @Cedon.  I did need to add this line of code to each "Submit" to have it directed to my handler.                   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="member_directory">
Thanks for the answer.